# NSNumber conversion-pair latitude and longitude

Tags: ios, nsnumber

```
NSNumber *a;

for(NSDictionary *item in[res valueForKey:@"snapshot"])
{
a=[item valueForKey:@"lat"];
NSLog(@"%@",a);
b=[item valueForKey:@"lng"];
NSLog(@"%@",b);
}
```

that writes on console :
        ("29.13","29.38","29.31","29.30","29.43" )
        ("94.13","94.38","93.30","94.58","94.34" )`

How could I get each values to convert double? I want to get each latitude and longitude pairs out of this output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your `NSLog`, the values you get from `valueForKey:` are `NSArrays`, not `NSNumber`. So simply go thru those arrays.

```
for(NSDictionary *item in[res valueForKey:@"snapshot"])
{
    NSArray* latitudesList  = [item valueForKey:@"lat"];
    NSArray* longitudesList = [item valueForKey:@"lng"];
    NSInteger idx = 0;
    NSInteger nb = MIN( latitudesList.count , longitudesList.count );
    for(NSInteger idx = 0; idx < nb; ++idx)
    {
      double lat = [[latitudesList  objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
      double lng = [[longitudesList objectAtIndex:idx] doubleValue];
      NSLog(@"Pair #%d = { %f , %f }", idx, lat, lng);
    }
}
```

Comment: thumbs up! Thanks AliSoftware.